# How do httpcontext.user.claims get its value in asp.net core assigned and is it session dependent?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, httpcontext, claims

this is a generic question. I want to know about httpcontext.user.claims. How this is getting its value? Is this session dependent? will this be automatically updated when a session expires?

Our web app is a federated app inside another app. That app controls the logging in  part. so once they are logged in the user can access our application and they send us a particular value needed for us through query string. we validate that value against the claims values by accessing httpcontext.user.claims. SO now the problem is inside our app httpcontext.user.claims has still the values of previous logged in user, if the browser is not closed or we havent cleared the cookies of the browser. SO its impossible for us to validate when logged in with another user from their app without closing browser or clearing cookie.
So i ant to know whether the httpcontext.user.claims is session dependent. Also when logging out they are actually doing session.Abandon() when they call logout method. Is it because our web app is creating another session, but we have no code written for any new session creation. F

Comment: Can you clarify more about the actual scenario and problems?

Comment: yes sure. I will update the question